# Simple logging class in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, oop, logging

I am trying to create **my own** logging class (don't want to use any side libraries). My application will send log requests from various classes, various threads and my main goal is to keep it queued properly and shown to user. With my current approach it looks a bit weird (as you can see I have to reasssure 2 times, that the `LogWork` was invoked properly).

```
public class Logger
{
    private static Logger mInstance;
    private LogLevel mLogLevel;
    private Queue<LogEntry> mLogQueue;
    private static readonly object mSyncObject = new object();


    public async void Log(LogLevel logLevel, string logMessage)
    {
        LogEntry le = new LogEntry(logLevel, logMessage, DateTime.Now);
        mInstance.mLogQueue.Enqueue(le);
        await Task.Run(() => LogWork(logLevel, logMessage));
    }


    private void LogWork(LogLevel logLevel, string logMessage)
    {
        lock (mSyncObject)
        {
            if (mLogQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                LogEntry le = mLogQueue.Dequeue();
                if (le != null)
                {
                    ShowLog(le);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    (...)
}
```

However that's not what I was aiming for. If I understand multithreading properly, my snippet will create a new thread for every log request and wait until `mSyncObject` becomes unlocked. How could I change it so there is **one** thread waiting for some logs to come? Is this even the correct approach?

Looking forward for any suggestions

Comment: Use a `Queue` to enqueue log requests and a running thread that watches the queue and dequeues values when there is stuff to work on.

Comment: @RonBeyer the thread will be running all the time then? I have tried it, the thread was checking the queue count in a `while(true)` loop, but that was rather a bad approach - it loaded my CPU a lot

Comment: You can use a [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) to let the tread sleep until something is put on the queue again.

Comment: You need to wake the thread when something is in the queue (when you enqueue) and put it to sleep when the queue is empty. You can use a `ManualResetEvent` for this like @fredrik suggested.

Comment: I will give it a try then. Thank you a lot!

Comment: You could leverage MSMQ (i don't have any working code at hand unfortunately)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Monitor.Wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait(v=vs.110).aspx), and [Monitor.Pulse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse(v=vs.110).aspx). You're writing a "consumer" from the producer-consumer pattern, there's a good [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) on it. Wait waits for control to be passed back to the thread on the lock object, pulse notifies threads waiting for control of the lock object.

From here on I'll refer to Monitor.Wait colloquially as "wait" or wait(obj)
and Monitor.Pulse as "notify" or notify(obj).

Here's how that would work:

1 - The LogWork thread waits to be notified inside the lock.

2 - The process creating the log notifies the LogWork thread when a log is added.

3 - LogWork checks for new LogEntry's, and if there are any, it does the logging.

4 - LogWork notifies, then goto step 1.

```
private void LogWork(...)
    lock(mSyncObject) {
        Monitor.Pulse(mSyncObject);
        while(Monitor.Wait(mSyncObject)) {
            if (mLogQueue.Count != 0) {
                LogEntry le = queue.dequeue();
                // handle log here
            }
            Monitor.Pulse(mSyncObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The snippet from where the log is created (the log "producer") would look like:

```
lock(mSyncObject) {
    Monitor.Wait(mSyncObject);
    mLogQueue.enqueue(myLogEntry);
    Monitor.Pulse(mSyncObject);
}
```

If you have many classes which all need to produce logs, then it may be prudent to have them inherit a Log method from a LogProducer class which encapsulates the waiting and notifying.

Comment: I would avoid pseudo-code unless you well-define *all* the methods. For example it would seem that your code would never be able to `enqueue` because it `wait(lockobj)` but the `LogWork` function has indefinitely locked the lock object. I'm not sure why the log producer would need to wait for the lock anyway, using a [Concurrent Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) would be thread-safe.

Comment: Yes Ron he stole your idea, I get it. The concurrent queue I agree would be better/easier. I also see a problem with the lock(lockObj) and the while(wait(lockObj)), how does the wait ever get open at this point?

Comment: In C#: once the LogProducer invokes Monitor.Pulse(), waiting threads are added to the ready queue, and once the LogProducer leaves its critical section the LogWork thread (now in the ready queue) gains control of the lock and becomes the active thread. I have clarified the use of methods in the pseudocode and added the critical section to the producer. Furthermore, it wasn't my intention to "steal" anyones ideas, only to expand on an answer @YogoWafel could use.

Comment: @Prometheus I really wouldn't consider it "stealing", I didn't post an answer, anybody is free to expand on comments.

Comment: @euid0 Your edit actually makes things worse unfortunately. The `LogWork` method (which is running in a thread) takes the lock and never releases it. This causes the `LogProducer` to wait at `lock(lockObj)` forever (because `LogProducer` never releases it), resulting in a hung-app. Again this is why you shouldn't use pseudocode in answers, you are mixing actual programming constructs (like `lock`) with imaginary ones and it makes the result very confusing.

Comment: @RonBeyer Monitor.Wait releases the lock on an object and blocks the current thread until it reacquires the lock. This is where the lock is passed. LogProducer releases the lock when it leaves the critical section.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using `lock(lockObj)` at the top. You can't mix `lock(lockObj)` and Monitor like that with the same object.

Comment: I've replaced the pseudocode with code for clarification.

Comment: @RonBeyer The lock statements here define the critical sections of the code.

Comment: @euid0 thanks for the explanation I had to restudy the difference between enter and wait.

Comment: @RonBeyer I was mainly making the leap as to your motivation based on a fault you presented that is a creative decision